# I have this DIV in the top left corner of my page. How can I make an anchor that fills this div?

Tags: html, css

```
#mydiv {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:83px;
height:83px;
}

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

That's my style for my DIV, which sits on the top left corner of my page.
I want this div to be click-able and go to a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#mydiv {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:83px;
height:83px;
}
#mydiv a
{
 display block;
 width:83px;
 height:83px;
}
<div id="mydiv"><a href="a">link</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in checking out the following article, for a brief explanation and a working example:

- [Filling a block level element with an anchor](http://web.archive.org/web/20101229225444/http://www.fiftyfoureleven.com/sandbox/filling-a-block-element-with-an-anchor-1/)

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to do this.  The first, and easiest, would be to just wrap your div with an anchor (`<a style="border: 0;" href="...">`) tag.

Or you can use css/javascript by adding an event listener to the div and adding a css pointer to it as well:

```
<div onclick="window.open(http...)" style="pointer: cursor;" >...</div>
```